# How to run threads concurrently in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Hi i have created a thread group which contains 10 transaction controller, each control has multiple number of HTTP request samplers.
Now to identify the bottleneck as per the requirement, each transaction control has to run one after another.
[image]
For ex: 30 threads- Register and login. send reports and logout is the scenario.
so, For each action i have created 1 transaction controller which contains required http sampler request. First i need to run register for 30 users. after getting the response for all 30 users then only login transaction controller should run. and so on.. one by one.
I tried creating multiple thread groups but i am fetching security tokens in each group. So if i create multiple thread group i cant call variable values of one thread group in another. 
So pls if anyone know the solution help me out, i am a beginner to jmeter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using only 'Synchronizing Timer' element of the JMeter. Please find below the brief description of this element:

- Synchronizing Timer: This element is used when you intentionally want to pause the users/threads at a specific step until the count of user mentioned in this element is reached

You can create your script in following structure:

- Transaction Controller for Register requests

  - HTTP Register Request1
  - HTTP Register Request2
- Transaction Controller for Login requests

  - HTTP Register Login1

    - Synchronizing Timer [Set the 'Number of Simulated Users to Group by' to 30 and Timeout based on your requirement [Recommended value to set is '300000' i.e 5 minutes]. Do not set Timeout to '0' otherwise your test will remain in running state forever if any of the user gets failed in previous step]
  - HTTP Register Login2
  - HTTP Register Login3

[image]

Note: In above example, you can see I have added synchronizing timer as a child of first HTTP sampler request of under Login transaction controller.

When the test reach at 'HTTP Register Login1' then before sending this request, it will perform the synchronizing timer and wait for all the users to complete the register action.

For beginners, the following blog posts of RedLine13 are very useful to jump start on JMeter:

```
https://www.redline13.com/blog/kb/
```

Also, the response time will definitely increase when you use the synchronizing timer because this timer will pause the test until all user reached the step and then perform the login operation. As all 30 users will perform the login action at the same time so the response time will go high as compared to the case when some users are doing registration and others doing login.

Kindly let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @ravi sharma, its very valuable information. i have implemented this on my test scenario but i have an doubt. say for example 10 transaction controller are there, 2nd controller response time expected is around 10-15 sec. but if i use synchronisation timer as per above, i am getting high response time. so how can i calculate the exact response time? i am implementing above logic to find bottle neck, i need to prepare a report with bottle neck. so i am using this timer. but if it is increasing response time then i ll be in trouble pls help me out this this. Thank you.

Comment: Avinash, can you please tell me what do you mean by exact response time?

Comment: Also, the purpose of sync timer is to send the http request [say Login] by all the users at the same time so it is expected that the response time would go up and you can consider the response time that you are getting in Aggregate report as correct.

Comment: Here exact time i am referring for the time taken for from server to response for sampler.. without using the timer i am getting low response time. But after using timer its taking bit more response time. in a report i need to mention the proper response time, i am worried that by using this timer if i mention the high response time, then it will be not proper.. that was my concern..

Comment: I would say both response time [with or without sync timer] are correct, then only thing that take the response time up [with sync timer] is the way users are hitting the requests in the second controller.

Comment: There are two scenarios here:
1. Running without sync timer: We have 250 users and all are performing scenario randomly. Few are at registration steps and others at login step so all 250 users are not hitting/sending the same request concurrently.
2. Running with sync timer: We have 250 users and all are performing scenario in a sequence and. All 250 are at registration step and then all 250 users at login step so all 250 users are hitting/sending the same request concurrently. [Continued]

Comment: You can ask for the Product owner/manager which scenario they want to see or cover then you can prepare your report accordingly.

Comment: I got requirement as scenario 2, ie concurrently running.  i have tested with 10 users with timer and without timer with 5 attempts and each time i got huge difference between the response time took for each controller.. thats why i am confused. just let me know is it ok with considering the response time with timer. if no then how can i handle this situation... thanks for ur valuable time and concern..

Comment: If the time taken for response from server is not affected by timer as per the requirement ie scenario 2. then i will follow as same as the report..

Comment: Yes, the response is not affected by the timer. I would recommend to mention both the scenarios in the report and highlight the reason for the difference. Its always good to provide as much information as possible :) this will also reflect your thorough approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "login" transaction to be kicked off only when all 30 users completed "register" transaction you need to:

1. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler between "register" and "login" transaction controllers
2. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the Test Action sampler and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to `30`

This way Test Action sampler will act as a "rendezvous point" so all 30 threads will "meet" there, this way you will get confidence that all 30 threads completed registration prior to starting logging in.

Example test plan:

[image: JMeter Test Action Synchronizing Timer]

Comment: Thanks a lot its working as per i  needed. But while comparing to the previous results ie without adding the test action with sync timer, the response delay was less. By adding this response time is bit greater than before... So can u pls tell me the cause... Thank you